# Python 3.4 Reading csv files ignoring spaces before and after items

Tags: csv, python-3.4, delimiter

I'm trying to read different csv files with different delimiters. I have it working for space delimiters but it doesn't seem to properly read them if the have an extra space before or after the data. 
The data is as follows:

```
Space Delimited Data
1 2 3
4 2 4 
3 4 5
3  5 6
3 4  5
 5 6 8
```

The last 3 rows would not be read properly (3  5 6, 3 4  5,  5 6 8) because of extra spaces before or after it. How can this be resolved?

My code is as follows:

```
def read(self, csv_file):
   if self.delimiter == '':
        with open(csv_file, newline='') as csvfile:
                try:
                    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(), delimiters='space,;-\|\t\\')
                    csvfile.seek(0)
                    f = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
                    for row in f:
                    self.raw_data.append(row)
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is a limitation of `csv.Sniffer` when working with small data sets. If you don't need to identify quote chars, I'd suggest replacing `csv` with `re.split`.

Comment: it that right? Thank Ywain.